# get a list of single property values in c# - reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I am struggling to understand how a reflection works in C#. I set a property of class name. When I use a method (below) to validate, i need to get a list of ProductName values. How to do this?

```
public class Product
{
    public string ProductName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class ClassName
 {
    public List<Product> Products
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
 }
```

App:

```
product.Add(new Product { ProductName = "whatever name 1" });
product.Add(new Product { ProductName = "whatever name 2" });
```

Method:

```
public bool Validate(object obj)
{
        PropertyInfo property = typeof(ClassName).GetProperty("Products");

        Value = (string)property.GetValue(obj, null); // how to get a list of values 
}
```

Comment: What is `GenericTransaction`?

Comment: Have you tried casting it to list?(List<Product>)property.GetValue(obj, null);

Comment: Although, it is able to decipher your question... Alex is right, you should at least take the time to read your own question and make sure all the keywords are correct (i.e product/Products as well as Product/GenericTransaction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast it to `List<Product>`:

```
public bool Validate(object obj) {
  if(!(obj is ClassName)) return false;
  PropertyInfo property = typeof(ClassName).GetProperty("Products");  
  Value = (List<Product>)property.GetValue(obj, null);
  return true;//or your own validation implemented here
}
```

Comment: i have tried this but i get error message : Object does not match target type.What is a Value data type?

Comment: @user2857908 are you sure `obj` is of type `ClassName`, that's your fault.

Comment: @user2857908 I updated the `Validate` method as how it should be, now you should see there is not any exception but the `Validate` returns `false`, because the `obj` passed in is not of type `ClassName`.